# jquery fancybox login box not load external php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, fancybox

I am trying to use Fancybox to display the login form like bellow

```
<div style="display:none">
    <form id="login_form" method="post" action="">
            <p id="login_error">Please, enter data</p>
        <p>
            <label for="login_name">Login: </label>
            <input type="text" id="login_name" name="login_name" size="30" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="login_pass">Password: </label>
            <input type="password" id="login_pass" name="login_pass" size="30" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <em>Leave empty so see resizing</em>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

the javascript for that is

```
$("#login_form").bind("submit", function() {

    if ($("#login_name").val().length < 1 || $("#login_pass").val().length < 1) {
        $("#login_error").show();
        $.fancybox.resize();
        return false;
    }

    $.fancybox.showActivity();

    $.ajax({
        type        : "POST",
        cache   : false,
        url     : "login.php",
        data        : $(this).serializeArray(),
        success: function(data) {
            $.fancybox(data);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

the HTML is

```
<a id="tip5" title="Login" href="#login_form"><?php echo "Login" ; ?></a>
```

when I click on the login link, it shows the login popup, but when i click on submit button, it closes the popup and refreshes the page.

actually, it should check the data and display data on the popup, not the refresh page.

Comment: Try using live() instead of bind().

Comment: I think you put the form in another file? So your jQuery/javascript code does not affect the form. I suggest putting all the html code including the form in the same file, then it should work fine.

Comment: Also since you use jQuery, you could just use the function submit(...) instead of bind('submit', ...)

Comment: form is in same file and also bind is same

Comment: Does the page still reload if you put "return false;" before the AJAX-request. If it does not, you´ll know there is an error with the AJAX code.

Comment: I don't see where you load the fancybox code, which version are you currently using?

Comment: Wait, do you run the bind in startup? ie:

$(function(){ /*run binds here*/ } );

Comment: dear @Arthur Wulf White  how to user function submit(...) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be more problems:

1. Fancybox is probably cloning the original HTML to put it into the popup. Therefore You need to use function `live` instead of `bind`.
2. It is possible that Fancybox could alter the form's ID in some way (check that with some DOM Inspector like FireBug for FireFox) and assure that the form's ID within a popup is the one You'd lived the submit event for.

I also prefer to use `event.preventDefault()` instead of returning false... My JS code would then be:

```
$("#login_form").live("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($("#login_name").val().length < 1 || $("#login_pass").val().length < 1) {
        $("#login_error").show();
        $.fancybox.resize();
        return false;
    }

    $.fancybox.showActivity();

    $.ajax({
        type        : "POST",
        cache   : false,
        url     : "login.php",
        data        : $(this).serializeArray(),
        success: function(data) {
            $.fancybox(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It would be better to use `.on()` (and jQuery 1.7+) instead since `.live()` has been deprecated (actually, `.delegate()` is recommended over `.live()`) ... just wondering why people still recommend using `.live()`

Comment: Maybe because jQuery is developing really fast last days and I have no time to watch the progress and becomes deprecated and what not... :-) Since I know it, I will try to suggest using `delegate` instead... Thank You for pointing out ;-)

Comment: jQuery 1.7 was released in November 2011 (http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/03/jquery-1-7-released/) ... so you had a 6 months jet lag ;)